# EF 6: The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to avoid "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once" exception without using ToList()?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var entities = _db.Trades.Where(t => t.A > 10);
int totalCount = entities.Count();
entities = entities.Where(t => t.B > 10);
int totalCountAfterAdditionalFilter = entities.Count();
```

I cannot call ToList() due to performance considerations. I know that I could just generate one more IQueryable, but that seems wrong (I have more filters like this). Could I somehow preserve/duplicate the IQueryable after my first call of Count()?

Thanks!

Comment: "I cannot call `ToList()` due to performance considerations" what performance considerations?  The query will need to get materialized at some point - why not in a `List`?

Comment: I have 1M+ records. It seems wrong to load all of them to memory at this stage. Before final filter is applied, I just want to get the count. Once filtering is finished I will materialize the query and it will return just 10 records or so.

Comment: Do you really need to know the two counts, or do you just need to know if any items are filtered out?  You can just filter on `t.B <= 10` and if there are any items, the two aren't the same, and you have your answer.  If you really do need the full counts, then that won't work.

Comment: Servy, in this case both counts are needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't achieve your desired result like that. As an alternative you can, however, save your filters to variables and then compose them as needed:

```
 Func<Trade, bool> filter1 = t => t.A > 10;
 Func<Trade, bool> filter2 = t => t => t.B > 10;
 Func<Trade, bool> compositeFilter = t => filter1(t) && filter2(t);

 int totalCount = _db.Trades.Count(filter1);
 int totalCountAfterAdditionalFilter  = _db.Trades.Count(compositeFilter);

 //Need more?
 compositeFilter = t => compositeFilter(t) && t.C > 100;
 int totalAfterMoreFilters = _db.Trades.Count(compositeFilter);
```

Comment: Don't the filter `Func`s have to be wrapped in an `Expression<T>` for LINQ to Entities to use them?

Comment: Problem is that I have more than 2 filters and some of them should not be triggered at times. But I like your idea. Maybe I need to find a way to dynamically generate the expression, save it to a variable and then reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

may be:

```
Trades.Where(x => x.A > 10).Select(x => new { i = 1, j = x.B > 10 ? 1 : 0}).
    GroupBy(y => y.i).
    Select(g => new { c = g.Count(), = g.Sum(z => z.j)})
```

That's give you the 2 informations in one query.